Change the folder structure in iceberg partitioned writer
I have an Iceberg table that is partitioned by both date and hour.
Currently, when using the Iceberg ORC partitioned writer, it creates daily folders, with each containing subfolders for each hour, and the data files are stored within these hourly folders.
Is there a way to adjust this folder structure so that all data files for a specific day are stored directly within the date folder, while still maintaining the partitioning of the table by both date and hour?
